# $L=[LL]$ for classical algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

> When $\operatorname{char}F=0$, show that each classical algebra $L=A_l,B_l,C_l$ or $D_l$ is equal to $[LL]$.

Since $L$ is a Lie algebra, we know that if $x,y\in L$, then $[x,y]=xy-yx\in L$. So $[LL]\in L$. We have to show that $L\in [LL]$, i.e. every element $z$ of $L$ is equal to $xy-yx$ for some $x,y\in L$. How might we choose $x,y\in L$ so that $xy-yx=z$?

Comment: That's not what you required to show. You are required to show that every element $z$ is a **linear combination** of commutators. Therefore it is enough to show this for all $z$ belonging to a basis of $L$. For classical algebras the first thing you should do is to calculate $$[e_{ij},e_{k\ell}],$$ where $e_{ij}$ stands for the $n\times n$ matrix with a single $1$ at column $j$, row $i$, and zeros elsewhere. That is only a starting point though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be helpful to know that $L$ is a simple Lie algebra, and that $[LL]$ is a Lie ideal in $L$.  This means that there are only two possibilities; either $[LL]=L$ or $[LL]=0$.  Why can we exclude the latter?

This answers your question, although it doesn't show how to compute $x$ and $y$ given $z$ as you've asked.  Such a constructive proof may be much more difficult.

Comment: Thanks, Jared. As to why we can exclude the latter, $[LL]=0$ would mean $xy=yx$ for all $x,y\in L$, so it suffices to provide a pair of matrices in $L$ that don't commute.

Comment: Hmm. Judging from the OP's question history, this exercise may have appeared before the simplicity of the classical algebras has been established. Can't tell for sure, and my copy of Humphreys is in my office :-/

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, it does appear before the simplicity of the classical algebras. It would be great if you have another method. Otherwise, it's okay, as I'm just learning by myself. I can sort of "skip ahead" :)

Comment: @PJMiller: You're right.  In general, a Lie algebra satisfying $[LL]=0$ is called abelian, and the classical lie algebras are not abelian.

Comment: @PJMiller: That other method involves calculations with those simple matrices. It is a useful exercise as it gives a preview of the phenomenon: commutators of vectors from root spaces land in the root space corresponding to the sum of the roots. The previous sentence may mean nothing to you at this point, but just do it! The case $A_\ell$ is easy, and follows from the rule
$$[e_{ij},e_{k\ell}]=\delta_{jk}e_{i\ell}-\delta_{\ell i}e_{kj}.$$ The other cases require a bit of case-by-case analysis.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen For $A_l$: To get the matrix $e_{ab}$ ($a\ne b$) we use $[e_{ac}, e_{cb}]$. To get the matrix $e_{ii}-e_{i+1,i+1}$ we use $[e_{i,i+1},e_{i+1,i}]$.

Comment: Well done, @PJMiller! I don't remember how you hanlde the other classical algebras, shouldn't be too difficult.